# How to copy XML elements except the root one line per element with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to format an XML file with XSLT one element per line without the root element and without white spaces. Here is my XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bank>
    <account>
        <acct_num></acct_num>
        <holder_name></holder_name>
        <holder_address></holder_address>
        <attr>
            <attr_type></attr_type>
            <attr_value></attr_value>
        </attr>
        <attr>
            <attr_type></attr_type>
            <attr_value></attr_value>
        </attr>
        <attr>
            <attr_type></attr_type>
            <attr_value></attr_value>
        </attr>
    </account>
    <account>
        <acct_num></acct_num>
        <holder_name></holder_name>
        <holder_address></holder_address>
        <attr>
            <attr_type></attr_type>
            <attr_value></attr_value>
        </attr>
        <attr>
            <attr_type></attr_type>
            <attr_value></attr_value>
        </attr>
        <attr>
            <attr_type></attr_type>
            <attr_value></attr_value>
        </attr>
    </account>
</bank>
```

And here is my XSLT file so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm currently using Saxon 9.7 as my XLST parser and my current XML output displays all the elements in just one line including the root. I've tried changing the apply-templates select to `<xsl:apply-templates select="account|node()"/>` but I keep getting the root tag `<bank></bank>` in the output:

```
<bank><account><acct_num/><holder_name/><holder_address/><attr><attr_type/><attr_value/></attr><attr><attr_type/><attr_value/></attr><attr><attr_type/><attr_value/></attr></account><account><acct_num/><holder_name/><holder_address/><attr><attr_type/><attr_value/></attr><attr><attr_type/><attr_value/></attr><attr><attr_type/><attr_value/></attr></account></bank>
```

I would like to have an output file just one line per each account without the root tag as follows:

```
<account><acct_num></acct_num><holder_name></holder_name><holder_address></holder_address><attr><attr_type></attr_type><attr_value></attr_value></attr><attr><attr_type></attr_type><attr_value></attr_value></attr></account>
<account><acct_num></acct_num><holder_name></holder_name><holder_address></holder_address><attr><attr_type></attr_type><attr_value></attr_value></attr><attr><attr_type></attr_type><attr_value></attr_value></attr></account>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have no root element but several top level elements you do not even create a well-formed XML document. Are you sure that is the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the output will not be well formed. The program that reads the file expects an input file without the root tag in the layout specified. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a template for those elements

```
<xsl:template match="account">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and only process them

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//account"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You don't need the identity transformation template, only the `xsl:strip-space`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it works like a charm but only with the first template. If I use both template declarations I get a blank output file.